# Display the number of data

Tags: php, html, html-table

After the data have been displayed on the page, I would like to displayed the number of records beside the table. How do I do that? Below is my coding:

```
</tr>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("write.xml");

echo $xml->getName();

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $child[0]->attributes();
     echo "</td>";

        foreach($child[0]->children() as $child2)
        {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $child2->getName() . ": " . $child2 ;
         echo "</td>";
        }

    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a counter and add +1 to each children, then outputs `echo $count;` and you will have your count,

```
$count = 0;
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
     $count++;
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo $child[0]->attributes();
     echo "</td>";

        foreach($child[0]->children() as $child2)
        {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $child2->getName() . ": " . $child2 ;
         echo "</td>";
        }

    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: See my update, there was a typo on my answer, it should be `$count++;` try now

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a simple counter?

```
$count = 0;
foreach(...) {
    ... display xml row
    $count++;
}
echo "Total rows: $count";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i = 0;

 foreach{
      //your code
      echo $i++;
 }
```